# how to use or link classes in angular 4 reactive approach

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am new to angular and saw many videos for model driven approach. they all make forms and initialize properties in component like below.

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    loginForm: FormGroup;
    model: loginModel;

ngOnInit() {
        this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
            'UserName': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
            'Password': new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
        })
    }

    onSubmit() {
        console.log(this.loginForm);
    }
}
```

I initialized my `fromGroup` specifying my class structure.
Is it possible to create linked model without declaring its structure in the component like in .net mvc(model.property name in html page) ?

Answer (score 0):

Your template would look like this :

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
 <input type="text" formControlName="UserName">
 <input type="password" formControlName="Password">
 <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Here is  link to the angular reactive-forms documentation : https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

**Edit after comment :**

You don't need reactive forms for your need, you could just use a plain object :

In the component side :

```
credentials = {};
```

The template :

```
<form>
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="credentials.login">
 <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="credentials.password">
<form>
```

Comment: i know it will look like this. the thing is i was trying to link model directly with html input elements without initializing one by one in ngOnInit method. is there no way without initializing elements in component we can initialize the model only?